# Why doesn't the Primary Key icon light up?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Just starting learning databases, in the following screenshots, why isn't the Primary Key lighting up for the column CustomerID? According to the indexes and the SQL query it is the Primary Key. I can't click on the icon, and I can't find anywhere else to make it the primary key.[image][image]

`SQL result`

Host: 127.0.0.1
Database: WMCRM
Generation Time: Nov 29, 2013 at 08:27 PM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.0.4.1 / MySQL 5.5.32
SQL query: show create table CUSTOMER;
Rows: 1

This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
Table   Create Table
CUSTOMER    CREATE TABLE `customer` (
 `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `LastName` text NOT NULL,
 `FirstName` text NOT NULL,
 `Address` text NOT NULL,
 `City` text NOT NULL,
 `State` text NOT NULL,
 `ZIP` text NOT NULL,
 `Phone` text NOT NULL,
 `Fax` text NOT NULL,
 `Email` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: all primary keys are unique, but not all unique keys are primary. Just because you set a unique key on a field doesn't make it the primary key. you have to explicitly SAY that a field is the primary key. You've named the key primary, but that's just a name. it could just as well be 'foo'. Unless you had `customer_id int auto_increment primary key` in your DDL, then it's not a primary key. it's just a unique key whose name happens to be "primary"

Comment: But for all other appearances it appears to marked as the primary key. Why does SQL query say CustomerID is the primary key?

Comment: run the query `show create table your_table_name`. it'll show you the exact sql needed to produce that table/index structure.

Comment: I didn't name it primary, it automatically did that, how would I tell it that CustomerID should be the primary key

Comment: added result of that query

Comment: so yep... it is a primary key. `PRIMARY KEY (CUstomerID)`. never used phpmyadmin. so... bug in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Primary key icon or link is available only when the action can be done. Is this situation, because this column is already the primary key, the action of making it the primary key is not possible.